# .click(function() not working on firefox with xampp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xampp

I am trying to get a .click() working so that it shows a div with other aspects of the form in it. For some reason the .click() isn't showing the rest of the form. all the spelling of id's and urls are correct and the javascript as a whole is not broken either.

here is some code:

The relevent html:

```
<FORM STYLE="display:inline;" id='1' FORM METHOD ="POST" ACTION="Quote Script.php"><br>

<div id='inputtext'>
 Customer: <input style='width: 150px;' type='text' id= '4' name='q' value=<?php echo $q;?>><br>
 </div>

 <div id='inputtext'>
  Date Revieved: <input type='text' id= '2' name='o' value=<?php echo $o;?>><br>
  </div>

  <div id='inputtext'>
  Promised Date: <input id= '3' name = 'p' type='text' value=<?php echo $p;?>>
  </div>

  </div>

  <div style="margin-left: 45%;">
  <input type='Button' id='Scans1' class="btn" value="Save">
  </div>

  </div>

  <div id='form1'>
```

The javascript/jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='jquery-1.10.2.js'>
$("#form1").hide();

$("#Scans1").click(function()
{

var Customer = $("#4").val();
var Dr= $("#2").val();
var Pd = $("#3").val();
$("#form1").show();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "mysql_quote1.php",
    data: {Customer: Customer, Dr: Dr, Pd: Pd}
    }).done(function(msg){
    alert("Data Saved:" +msg);
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: You have to put your JavaScript code in new `<script></script>` blocks in order to work. Also: avoid using a number for an element id.

Comment: FYI, This has nothing to do with `xampp`. It was just errors in your jquery code.

Comment: ok thanks guys but for some reason it still isn't working

Answer (score 2):

Any script tag with attribute src specified will ignore its content. BTW, you should wait for DOM ready, or put your second script tag just before the closing body's tag: `</body>`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='jquery-1.10.2.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () { //<= this is document ready handler
    $("#form1").hide();

    $("#Scans1").click(function () {

        var Customer = $("#4").val();
        var Dr = $("#2").val();
        var Pd = $("#3").val();
        $("#form1").show();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "mysql_quote1.php",
            data: {
                Customer: Customer,
                Dr: Dr,
                Pd: Pd
            }
        }).done(function (msg) {
            alert("Data Saved:" + msg);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I have everything in the right place and have added the new tags but it still wont show the rest of the form when I click the button.

Comment: Is the click event fired or not? Use a alert() to check

Comment: the event is not fired.

Comment: Ok, check your console for error. Provide a jsfiddle which reproduce your issue, you are doing something wrong for sure

Comment: could the bootstrap im using be causing errors in the javascript?

Comment: [13:05:51.941] SyntaxError: syntax error @ http://localhost/ScanTimes/Quote%20Script.php:342

Comment: [13:05:51.941] The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.

Comment: So your html seems not valid. I'd suggest you to read some basic tutorials on how to create an html page

Comment: the html cant be invalid if it has worked perfectly fine on chrome

Comment: Each browser can parse invalid html diferently, test in IE and see if it works or not. For example, your form tag should be in lowercase, not uppercase. What about your doctype, how do you declare it, etc...